# About missing utxo in chainstate

Tags: synchronization, utxo

I'm trying to obtain up-to-date database of the UTXO and keep updating it as new block is added.

And for this, I want to use chainstate as a starting point of synching.

I parsed chainstate to obtain remaining utxo at 784468th block, and put them in DB.

The problem I have right now is this.

I checked the transactions' vin at the next block (784469th), and checked whether utxos used in the next block are present in my DB. However, there are about about 50 missing utxos in DB that were definately created before 784468th block and used at 784469th block.


I really want to know why this happens.


The parse tool that I'm using is here. https://github.com/in3rsha/bitcoin-utxo-dump

Comment: Can you be more specific? Like pointing out what data is supposed to be missing?

Comment: Did your node follow a reorg?

Comment: @sr_gi For example, vin of transaction at the next block should be present in the chainstate of the current block. However, some vin are missing in the csv file that I got from parsing the chainstate.

Answer (score 1):

I found this comment in one of the issues:

> Sorry that I was too concise. dumptxoutset output is just binary, but I thought it could be used as a first step of bitcoin-utxo-dumo instead of reading the chainstate and avoiding the issue "This tool may corrupt your chainstate database"

It suggests to me that this tool corrupted your DB because it was not using the suggested binary method included in core.

https://github.com/in3rsha/bitcoin-utxo-dump/issues/43#issuecomment-1491621118